# Node JS app only display the first JSON object. Why?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, twilio

I am trying to write a json object in my node application, integrating the Twilio API. When console logging the object all objects are returned properly but when I write it to the document only the first object is written. Why? How should I change the code to see the same written response as in my console log.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var accountSid = 'xxx'; 
    var authToken = 'xxx'; 

    var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken); 

    client.messages.list({ 
        from: "xxx", 
        to: "xxx" 
    }, function(err, data) { 
        data.messages.forEach(function(message) { 
                console.log(message.body); // THIS WILL DISPLAY ALL OBJECTS
                res.json(message.body); // THIS WILL ONLY DISPLAY THE FIRST OBJECT 
        });
    });
});

app.listen(1337);
```

I am new to Node JS and think this is easy to solve, but I still can’t find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`res.json(...);`](https://expressjs.com/api.html#res.json) sends back the response. You are doing that in the first iteration over the array, hence the client only gets the first message.

If you want to extract `body` from all messages and send all of them back, then do that. Create an array with the data you want and send it back. Example:

```
res.json(data.messages.map(function(message) {
    return message.body;
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only call `res.json` once per request. You're calling it multiple times in a loop. The first time you call it, the browser receives the response, and you'll get a `headers already sent` exceptions (or something like that) for all other res.json calls.

Answer (score 0):

res.json actually does a data conversion to JSON. I'd be willing to bet there is something it is not dealing with, or it's simply screwing it up. If the response from Twilio is already json, you probably don't need to do that. Try res.send, instead, which just returns whatever you got back.